# Como mostrar un jsp desde un controlador en Java?

Tags: java, jsp, spring

Tengo este formulario en un jsp "principal", quiero que al darle clic al boton me mande a otro jsp "consulta"

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control text-lowercase" id="password" name="password"/>

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" value="Entrar" onclick=""/>
```

Este es mi controlador el primer metodo es el que llama al jsp principal y quiero que al dar click en el boton me mande al segundo metodo para que se muestre el jsp consulta

```html
@RequestMapping(value= "/Principal", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String irPaginaLogin(){
  return "/principal";
}

@@RequestMapping(value= "/views/consulta", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public String operacionConsulta(@ModelAttribute("consulta") ConsultaVo entrada, HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
request.getSession.setAttribute("consulta", entrada);
entrada.setFolio("MB123S");
List<EntidadDatos> listEntidad;
listEntidad = service.consultaFolio(entrada);

return "views/consulta";
}
```

como puedo hacer que me redirija al otro jsp?

Answer (score 0):

Podrías revisar la [documentación](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-redirecting-passing-data) que muestra un ejemplo:

```
@PostMapping("/files/{path}")
public String upload(...) {
    // ...
    return "redirect:files/{path}";
}
```